# Qual o código e linguagem fazem a tag input fazer o que faz?

Tags: html

A tag input é uma tag html, ou seja linguagem de marcação, no entanto essa tag executa instruções como de uma linguagem de programação.

Afinal como a tag "input file", faz para acessar o sistema operacional e trazer o arquivo selecionado?

Como alterar a mensagem:"Nenhum arquivo selecionado" sem javascript ?

Comment: Essas tags sinalizam para o navegador que ele deve fazer alguma coisa. A implementação da ação delas está no código fonte do navegador, não na página/aplicação Web que você faz.

Comment: A pergunta está um pouco confusa, especialmente o último parágrafo que não parece ter relação com o resto. Não sei se dá para responder a pergunta facilmente, já que teria que explicar muita coisa, o que tornaria a pergunta muito ampla. Talvez dê para fazer um resumo, sei lá. Se melhorar a pergunta, deixando ela um pouco mais específica, fica mais fácil obter uma resposta.

Comment: Não é muito bem direcionado a sua pergunta, mas como a dúvida beira para a ideia de "como o HTML é processado?", fica aqui um material amigável:
http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/

Answer (score 13):

O input não é parte de uma linguagem de programação especifica, ele é parte de algo que chamamos `interface` (https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html#input.file-interface), cada navegador tem um motor próprio de renderização que vai implementar esta `interface` cada qual é feito na sua propria linguagem de programação, a maioria dos motores são escritos em [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), mas existem motores que são escritos em [c](/questions/tagged/c) ou [java](/questions/tagged/java).

### Lista de motores mais populares

- Chrome e Opera usam o motor [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink) (fork do Webkit)
- Safari usa o motor [Webkit](https://webkit.org)
- InternetExplorer usa o motor [Trident](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (descontinuado em favor do EdgeHTML e MS Edge)
- Microsoft Edge usa o motor [EdgeHTML](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/tag/edgehtml/)
- Firefox usa o motor [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Gecko)

Quando você colocar um elemento assim dentro do html:

```
<input type="file">
```

O navegador inicialmente vai ler como texto, mas então ele vai processar o documento todo e começa a gerar o que chamamos de "widgets" (os widgets gerados baseados no sistema operacional ou não), isso pode ocorrer em quanto a página esta carregando ou somente quando ela termina de carregar (vai depender do tipo de buffer).

Não há como você manipular, a estrutura HTML e XML é renderizada pelo navegador e não por um script externo, os motores já são compilados, a única maneira de alterar de verdade seria criar o seu próprio motor, ou pegar um existente e modificar (tal como a google fez com o Webkit)

No entanto com CSS e HTML é possível simular um input customizado assim:

```js
var fakeInput   = document.querySelector(".file-customizado");
var realInput   = document.querySelector(".file-customizado input[type=file]");
var selectLabel = document.querySelector(".file-customizado .label");
var pathFile    = document.querySelector(".file-customizado .path");

//Remove o path do arquivo, assim é exibido apenas o nome do arquivo
function basename(path) {
   path = String(path);
   var d = path.split(/\\|\//);
   return d[d.length - 1];
}

//O input customizado dispara o evento no input real
fakeInput.onclick = function() {
     realInput.click();
};

//O input detecta a troca de arquivo para mostrar que o input não esta vazio no label
realInput.onchange = function() {
    if (realInput.value) {
       selectLabel.className = "label hide";
       pathFile.innerHTML = basename(realInput.value);
       pathFile.className = "path";
    } else {
       pathFile.className = "path hide";
       selectLabel.className = "label";
    }
};
```

```css
.file-customizado {
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f00;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.file-customizado input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: -9990px;
    left: -9999px;
}
.file-customizado .label, .file-customizado .path {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.file-customizado .hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="file-customizado">
    <input type="file" name="campo">
    <span class="label">Selecionar...</span>
    <span class="path hide"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54204/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-qual-o-codigo-e-linguagem-fazem-a-t)

Answer (score 0):

O elemento **input** é próprio da linguagem de marcação HTML,e faz parte de um modelo para um conjunto de dados, o formulário, associado a um método e ação URI.  [HTML elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html)

O funcionameto para o acesso dos arquivos no sistema operacional
ocorre resumidamente da seguinte forma:

Quando o usuário clica no botão relativo ao elemento "input file", o navegador faz uma requisição ao servidor (no caso o próprio sistema operacional), e estabelece uma conexão com o servidor através de um [socket de rede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).

Cada plataforma possui uma biblioteca Web com um script interno(ou interface) exemplo [.Net Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045(v=vs.100).aspx)  de modo a tornar a conexão possível, onde ocorre o apelidado [handshake-aperto de mão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.ports.serialport.handshake(v=vs.110).aspx).

Desta forma é feita uma chamada no Sistema Operacional (lado do servidor) que 
abre sua própria caixa de diálogos (no Windows [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)) contendo 
uma lista de arquivos para seleção.

Após a seleção do arquivo, a transferência é realizada através do protocolo 
apropriado, HTTP ou outro dependendo do tipo de arquivo.

Alguns meta dados (nem todos) do(s) arquivo(s) selecionados ficam disponíveis para manipulação no browser.

O **HTMLInputElement** [interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) fornece propriedades especiais e métodos 
(para além do normal HTMLElement interface que ele também tem à sua 
disposição por herança) para manipular o layout e apresentação dos 
elementos de entrada.

A mensagem "Nenhum arquivo selecionado", faz parte do código interno do navegador e desconheço uma forma de alterá-la sem javascript.