# Enviar um dos valores do select e colar em um input text?

Tags: php, javascript

Como enviar o valor de uma das opções de um "select" para um input text?

Comment: sua pergunta esta muito vaga vou votar para fechacao

Comment: Vc poderia fornecer mais informações a pergunta? Não estou conseguindo entender o que vc quer.

Comment: @Gagel Gagel sou novo no forum, na sua opinião como seria a forma menos vaga de preguntar o que eu perguntei?

Comment: @Gagel Gagel *perguntar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado um HTML assim:

```
<select id="meuSelect">
    <option value="a">Alfa</option>
    <option value="b">Beta</option>
    <option value="g">Gama</option>
</select>
<input type="text" />
```

podes guardar os objetos numa variável assim:

```
var select = document.getElementById('meuSelect');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
```

depois junta um auscultador de evento ao `select`. Deves escutar pelo evento `change` e na callback o `select` será o `this`. O resto é simples:

```
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    input.value = this.value;
    // se quiseres o texto usa 
    // var option = this.children[this.selectedIndex];
    // input.value = option.innerHTML;
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oz0z6Lcg/1

Comment: perfeito muito obrigado. Para bom entendedor um pingo é letra.

Comment: @MagicHat ótimo. Se quiseres podes marcar a pergunta como aceite. E o mesmo [na outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126977/129) - podes marcar como aceite uma das respostas.

Comment: você diz clicar no ícone que parece um visto do professor? Em relação a opção de pegar o texto dentro do elemento, sua solução trás todas as opções e as tags também, como pegar só o texto de uma das opções selecionadas? Qual outra pergunta se refere?

Comment: @MagicHat sorry, tinha um bug. Corrigi :)

Comment: Perfect, like magik ;) Point for you!