# O que é rel="preload"?

Tags: html5, html-tags

Eu vi em um trecho de código de um site uma definição mais ou menos assim:

```
<link rel="preload" href="caminho/para/o/script.js" as="script">
```

Nunca tinha visto esse código antes.

Eu gostaria de saber: O que significa esse `rel="preload"`? É alguma especificação do HTML5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content), o valor de `preload` no atributo `rel=` do elemento `<link>` permite que você escreva solicitações de busca declarativas em seu `<head>`, especificando recursos que suas páginas precisarão muito logo após o carregamento, o que você deseja iniciar a pré-carga no início do ciclo de vida de um carregamento de página, antes que a máquina de renderização principal do navegador entre em operação.

Isso garante que eles estejam disponíveis antes e que tenham menos chances de bloquear a primeira renderização da página, levando a melhorias no desempenho.

Você normalmente usaria algo assim:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
```

Aqui no entanto, vamos usar um valor `rel` de `preload`, que transforma o `<link>` elemento em um pré-carregador para praticamente qualquer recurso que desejarmos:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS and CSS preload example</title>

  <link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">
  <link rel="preload" href="main.js" as="script">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>bouncing balls</h1>
  <canvas></canvas>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Aqui estamos pré-carregando nossos arquivos CSS e JavaScript para que eles estejam disponíveis assim que forem necessários durante a renderização da página mais tarde. Este exemplo é um pouco trivial, mas os benefícios podem ser vistos com maior clareza, mais tarde na renderização os recursos são descobertos e maiores são.

Recursos apontados para dentro de um arquivo CSS, como fontes ou imagens, ou imagens maiores e até arquivos de vídeo pode ter benefícios também se adicionados com o atributo `preload`, sendo os seguintes possíveis benefícios:

- Priorizar o carregamento de recursos com mais precisão.
- Combinar pedidos futuros, reutilizando o mesmo recurso, se apropriado.
- Aplicar a política de segurança de conteúdo correta ao recurso.
- Defina os cabeçalhos de solicitação (header) de [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) corretos para ele.

---

### Que tipos de conteúdo podem ser pré-carregados com link `rel="preload"`?

Com o atributo `as="..."` você pode definir os seguintes tipos de documentos.

- `as="audio"`: arquivo de áudio
- `as="video"`: arquivo de vídeo.
- `as="document"`: documento HTML destinado a ser incorporado dentro de um `<frame>` ou `<iframe>`.
- `as="fetch"`: recurso a ser acessado por um pedido de busca ou [**`XmlHttpRequest`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (ou [**`fetch`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)), como um arquivo `ArrayBuffer` ou `JSON`.
- `as="font"`: arquivo de fonte.
- `as="image"`: arquivo de imagem.
- `as="script"`: arquivo JavaScript.
- `as="style"`: arquivos de estilo.
- `as="track"`: arquivo WebVTT.
- `as="worker"`: um Worker web JavaScript ou trabalhador compartilhado.
- `as="embed"` e `as="object"`: recurso a ser incorporado dentro de um elemento `<embed>` ou `<object>`.

---

### Preloads não usados

Se você pré-carregar algum recurso como por exemplo:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS and CSS preload example</title>

  <link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>bouncing balls</h1>
  <canvas></canvas>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

mas não usa-lo provavelmente o console do navegador vai emitir uma mensagem semelhante a isto:

```
The resource http://site/style.css was preloaded using link
preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's
load event. Please make sure it wasn't preloaded for nothing.
```

Note que usar o `<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">` só vai pré-carregar o CSS e priorizar (conforme você configurar a prioridade), ele não vai estilizar o documento pra você, ainda é necessário chamar o:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Guilherme fiquei com uma dúvida. Na Documentação da W3C diz o seguinte: "*If the preload keyword is used as an optimization to initiate earlier fetch then no additional feature detection checks are necessary: browsers that support preload will initiate earlier fetch, and those that do not will ignore it and fetch the resource as previously. Otherwise, if the application intends to rely on preload to fetch the resource, then it can execute a feature detection check to verify that it is supported.*"

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi não precisa ter 2 `<link>` pro mesmo CSS ou então serão serão duas Requisições. Apenas `<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">` já seria suficiente, pois o Browser que não reconhecer o Preload vai carregar o CSS normalmente, mesmo com *rel="preload"* na tag... https://w3c.github.io/preload/#dfn-preload-keyword

Comment: @hugocsl acho que você entendeu errado o texto em inglês, a mensagem parece que fala sobre suporte de navegadores sobre o preload, não sobre adicionar um link[rel=stylesheet] e um link[rel=preload] seria uma redundância. Tanto que efetuei um teste, criei uma pagina apenas com rel=preload para um css com isto `h1 { font-size: 48pt }` e nada ocorreu.

Comment: @hugocsl editei a resposta, veja a explicação

Comment: Legal Guilherme valeu pela explicação! Achei que repetindo o link para o mesmo arquivo faria com que o Browser fizesse duas requisições, mas parece que não é isso

Comment: @hugocsl ele faz sim a requisição HTTP para o servidor, ele só não processa/renderiza. Uma coisa é o download, outra coisa é o motor do navegador renderizar, são duas coisas separadas que se comunicam ou não, tanto que um motor de renderização HTML/CSS pode ser usado para carregar arquivos locais ou até implementar outras estruturas fora da web.

Comment: Tenho que ler mais sobre "How Browsers Work" rss, []´s

Comment: @hugocsl um dica inicial, o motor de renderização de cada navegador: Firefox é o Gecko, Chrome e Opera são o Blink, IE = Trident, MSEdge é o EdgeHTML, o Safari, Android Browser usam o Webkit. Antigamente o Opera (até o 12) era o Presto.... e por ai vai, aproveite e leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187977/3635

Answer (score 3):

Para começar precisamos entender o que é o `rel`, ele permite que você especifique e pré-carregue recursos que sua página vai precisar antes da renderização principal do navegador, é comumente utilizada pra arquivos `CSS`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
```

Utilizando o `rel="preload"` você pode especificar qualquer recurso para ser pré-carregado, como por exemplo um `JS`

```
<link rel="preload" href="funcao.js" as="script">
```

Você ainda pode usar o `as` para especificar o tipo de recurso que será carregado.

A principal vantagens desse pré-carregamento é que os esses recursos estarão disponíveis antes da renderização da página.